# Filemaker XML Query: Using OR?

Tags: xml, filemaker

How do you do an OR query with Filemaker XML webpublishing?

```
string query = @"http://" + getfmserver() + "/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=CUSTOMERS&-lay=CUST_VIEW&PhoneNumber=N&"+<<what goes here??>>+"&-find";
```

Here I'm checking to see if a customer has a phone number on file; but I'd like to return results if the customer has NO phone number on file OR NO email address on file.

I understand I need to use the -lop tag but the documentation isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `-lop=or` and list both criteria:

```
?-db=CUSTOMERS
  &-lay=CUST_VIEW
  &PhoneNumber=N
  &EmailAddress=N
  &-lop=or
  &-find
```

To build more complex queries read about the `-query` command; for very complicated ones write a script.